# System.IO.IOException: Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream

Tags: c#, .net, exception

My solution is deployed on a windows Server 2003 and it communicates with a server 2008 R2 in DMZ

I'm receiving an error message when trying to create a Jira Request

> System.IO.IOException: Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the
>   transport stream. at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[]
>   buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)   at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)   at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer,
>   AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)   at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken
>   message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)   at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32
>   count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)   at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst,
>   Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)   at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult
>   lazyResult) at System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication(Object
>   state)   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object
>   userData)   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode
>   code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)   at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)  at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   ignoreSyncCtx)   at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) at
>   System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)  at
>   System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) 
>   at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
>   size) at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async) --- End
>   of inner exception stack trace ---

The used protocol is : "TLS" 
I used this code snippet after reading forums :

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCerts);
```

Comment: It looks like the server rejected the request and closed the connection.  I would look at the examples of TLS project at codeproject to find sample code.  Most servers to prevent haskers from getting onto the site will not respond to bad requests and simply close the connection.

Comment: You may want to check which version of TLS you are using. If it is an older version it may be blocked. A quick search looks like Windows 2003 only supports TLS 1.0.  I think it is common for sites to require TLS 1.2. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2011/10/02/support-for-ssltls-protocols-on-windows/

Comment: J'ai rajouté ce bout de code 
 : ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
                System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =   System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3  | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls  mais l'exception persiste